# Display value from nestedMap in Angular with *ngfor

Tags: angular

I have an array like this in my angular component

```
map: Map<string, Map<string, string>>;
```

the value i need to display in ui is inside the second map
So i am trying to iterate over the map and within that get the value from the innermap and display in ui .
something like this

```
<li *ngFor="let row of map | keyvalue">
   <div ng-repeat ="item in row">
      {{item.value}}
   </div>
```

But it says

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Can I get an idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: I wonder where you found `ng-repeat` syntax in Angular(not AngularJS)?

Comment: I suppose to you foreach your map in constructor or nginit in component and display the result that you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following syntax instead of `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let row of map | keyvalue">
        {{row.key}}
        <div *ngFor="let innerRow of row.value | keyvalue">
            {{innerRow.key}}
            {{innerRow.value}}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @junaidp: Please do consider upvoting the answer as well! Thank you!